# Vue.js static hosted single-page app

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I would like to use vue.js, and compile everything to a static site on Amazon S3.  This seems to be possible with [Nuxt](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/introduction-to-server-rendered-vue-js-apps-with-nuxt-91dbfd80795a), but it seems to generate separate HTML files for your routes.  Is it not possible to generate a single-page static app with vue.js?

Comment: With the official webpack template you will get this. Everthing will be compiled to a html + bundle.js file. You do not need Nuxt for this.

Comment: I can build using webpack, and I see a build.js in my build folder, but there is no HTML file in that folder.  What do I upload to S3?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this template https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack with this few console commands to get what you want:

```
 npm install -g vue-cli
 vue init webpack your-project
 cd your-project
 npm install
 npm run dev
 npm run build
```

after the build command you will have a `dist` folder that can be uploaded to any static filehoster. It includes a `index.html` and static js + css files, including `bundle.js` and map files. I tested it a few secounds ago for you.